# Django export PDF directly from view

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm wondering if it's somehow possible to process the PDF export directly in the main view, and have it triggered by a button click in the template. The reasoning is that in the main view (dispatcher_single) I have 300 lines of code of data manipulation (including charts) that I would like to export to PDF and would like to avoid having to copy/paste all this code from main view to the PDF export view.

Main view with a bunch of calculations:

```
views.py
def dispatcher_single(request, pk):
    dispatcher = Dispatcher.objects.select_related("company", "location").get(id=pk)

    # data manipulation here (about 300 lines of code)

    context = {
        'dispatcher': dispatcher
        'bunch_of_other_data': data
    }
    return render(request, 'dispatchers/dispatcher-single.html', context)
```

Another view for exporting to PDF:

```
views.py
from renderers import render_to_pdf

def dispatcher_statement_form(request, pk):
    dispatcher = Dispatcher.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {
        'dispatcher': dispatcher,
    }
    response = renderers.render_to_pdf("pdf/statement_form.html", context)
    if response.status_code == 404:
        raise Http404("Statement form not found.")

    filename = "Statement_form.pdf"
    content = f"inline; filename={filename}"
    download = request.GET.get("download")
    if download:
        content = f"attachment; filename={filename}"
    response["Content-Disposition"] = content
    return response
```

And the render function:

```
renderers.py

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse("Invalid PDF", status_code=400, content_type='text/plain')
    return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
```

Comment: Can you not write the 300 lines of data manipulation as a class or as function(s), so that all you need to do is import and invoke it in the two places it its used? I have a pseudo-app called "utils" where I put all sorts of shared code similar to this.  You might also be able to write it as a mixin class and add the mixin to both views, if you switched to CBVs.

Comment: Thanks, Nigel! The function/class suggestion is a good idea, I'll see if I can do it. So far, I've only worked with FBV, so I need to look into mixins. Thank you!